# Why can't I write to my mounted vfat partition?

Tags: fstab

I reinstalled Ubuntu yesterday, and after using 'Disk Utility' one of my partitions doesn't allow to get files saved.

This is what the fstab file looks like

```
proc                                       /proc            proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid                                                           0  0  
#Entry for /dev/sda9 :
UUID=22d34341-7a5b-4d89-a3c0-6e147bc08dea  /                ext4         errors=remount-ro                                                             0  1  
#Entry for /dev/sda2 :
UUID=8E4460D94460C615                      /media/RECOVERY  ntfs      defaults,nls=utf8,umask=0222                                                  0  0  
#Entry for /dev/sdc1 :
UUID=1A2774677A17F3F7                      /media/Trascend  ntfs      defaults,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177  0  0  
#Entry for /dev/sda3 :
UUID=9ED06370D0634D99                      /media/sda3      ntfs     nls=iso8859-1,rw,umask=000                                                    0  0  
 #Entry for /dev/sda5 :
UUID=B239-5BD2                             /media/sda5      vfat     iocharset=utf8,rw,umask=000                                                   0  0  
#Entry for /dev/sda6 :
UUID=660325B85226874E                      /media/sda6      ntfs-3g  users                                                                         0  0  
 #Entry for /dev/sda7 :
 UUID=568A57020A03D259                      /media/sda7      ntfs     nls=iso8859-1,umask=000,user                                                  0  0  
#Entry for /dev/sda8 :
UUID=0ab8649b-acb5-4897-a44a-2b95856aef65  none             swap     sw                                                                            0  0  

     /dev/sda5                                  /media/sda5      vfat     defaults                                                                      0  0
```

The one giving me problems is "sda5" and it seems to appear twice, one time at the very end.

Comment: You should edit fstab and delete the last entry.

Comment: @mikewhatever: please make that comment into an answer :)

Comment: Done and done!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should edit fstab and delete the last entry. To edit the file, run

```
gksudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

...save and exit when done.